# Position fixed makes Material UI Switch component not change

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

After many tests I found that my Material UI switch is not working because I have set the position to fixed, if I just change that to relative everything works perfectly.
Couldn't find any answers to this problem, hopefully somebody can help.

Thanks

```
<Box sx={{position: 'fixed', right:'10px'}}>
          <FormControlLabel control={<Switch onChange={handleClick}  /> } />
            <DarkModeIcon color='disabled'/>
            <LightModeIcon color='primary'/>
        </Box>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a codesandbox with the issue replicated so we can have a look. When I try with your code  the switch seems to be working. Thanks

Comment: This is strange, I can't replicate the issue on codesandbox, it works well there. I also discovered that if I just change right:'10px' to left:'10px' it works perfectly.

Comment: Try to inspect your elements in case an icon hides the click able element?

Comment: Or probably is another element from you DOM that goes on top of your Switch and that's why you can't click on it